# Input is supposed to be list but is taking a str input and producing an error

Tags: python, list, append, attributeerror

I am creating a program which is similar to a todo list, but the append method doesn't seem to match the datatype

```
   match user_action:
       case "add":
           todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"

           file = open('todos.txt', 'r')
           todos = file.readline()
           file.close() 
           todos.append(todo)

           file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
           file.writelines(todos)
           file.close()
```

expecting the user input to get appended in the todos list

Comment: It's not quite clear what the task is, and thus - what the exact problem is.  `todos` is a string, not list, so yeah,  no `append` method. Probably yoe mean `readlines()`

Comment: Why are you writing like this todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n". Instead use the line separator inside the input function.

Comment: @aws_sangram, they want to add new line to user input, not a new line after the prompt

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue where the input is supposed to be a list but it's taking a string input and producing an error, you need to initialize the `todos` variable as a list instead of a string. Here's the updated code:

```
match user_action:
case "add":
    todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"
    file = open('todos.txt', 'r')
    todos = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    todos.append(todo)
    file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
    file.writelines(todos)
    file.close()
```

Explanation:

- The `readlines()` method is used to read all the lines from the file and store them as a list in the `todos` variable.
- The `append()` method is then used to add the new todo item to the `todos` list.
- Finally, the `writelines()` method is used to write the updated `todos` list back to the file.

Remember to import the necessary modules and ensure that the file todos.txt exists before running this code.